# PHP count total quantity in cart

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have `$_SESSION['products']` to saved multiple cart items, I want to have total quantity to be show up on header

I try to get total quantity with below script:

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['products'])) {

      $totalQty = 0;

      foreach($_SESSION['products'] as $itemQty){
          $totalQty += $itemQty;
      }

  }

  echo $totalquantity;
```

I `print_r($_SESSION['products'])` get current items in cart below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
         [p_id] => 31 
         [p_name] => Product 31
         [p_price] => 28.80
         [p_qty] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
         [p_id] => 46 
         [p_name] => Product 46
         [p_price] => 18.00
         [p_qty] => 3
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
         [p_id] => 12 
         [p_name] => Product 12
         [p_price] => 63.00
         [p_qty] => 1
    )
)
```

How to loop through an $_SESSION and get a total [p_qty] in an array dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
echo array_sum(array_column($_SESSION['products'], 'p_qty'));
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/462285)

Comment: thanks, works awesome! for those who use PHP < 5.5 can use library -> https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method For - Total Quantity Calculate in Codeigniter**

```
<?php 
foreach($this->cart->contents() as $itemQty){
$totalQty+=$itemQty['qty'];
}
?>
<?php echo $totalQty;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, fetch all data, then write this code :

```
$total_quantity = array_sum(array_column($carts, "quantity"));
```

Here $carts are all cart data and the other one is the counting column, which you want to count.